# Datagridview column in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

how can i get a column to be able to contain a textbox or an image? 
I am trying to add any type of data to that one column, wether it be text or an image. How would i do this in C#?

ok, programmatically, i am going to have both textboxes and images in the same column...how do i do it?

Comment: This was asked just the other day, alternating DataGridView Text and Image cells: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481142/c-sharp-datagridview-image-and-text-on-the-same-row/11481229#comment15162135_11481229 - if you want text and image  combined let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example. However you will need to handle the default image (in absence it is going to have a cross marked image). Refer to this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.image.aspx)

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Image");

        dataTable.Rows.Add("Desert", @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("Tulips", @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg");

        dataTable.AcceptChanges();

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn textColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        textColumn.DataPropertyName = "Name";
        textColumn.HeaderText = "Name";
        textColumn.Width = 100;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(textColumn);

        DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        imageColumn.DataPropertyName = "Image";
        imageColumn.HeaderText = "Image";
        imageColumn.Width = 100;            
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imageColumn);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewImageColumn)
        {
            string imagePath = (e.Value ?? "").ToString().Trim();
            if(System.IO.File.Exists(imagePath))
                e.Value = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a `TextBox` control inside the `DataGridView`, click the smart tag and select Add Column. Select `DataGridViewTextColumn` and click Add. Select `DataGridViewImageColumn` if you choose image.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't show the OP  how to have both textboxes and images in the same column...